# Unable to add firebase package to project in Xcode: authentication failed because no credentials were provided

Tags: firebase, swiftui, xcode14, xcode14.3

## Context

Xcode: 14.3 (I even tried 14.2 and 14.1, but got the same error) macOS: 13.3.1 (a) (22E772610a)

tldr/video: https://www.loom.com/share/3ddee7d80007420592297c9421737ea5

Similar to this issue https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/7777

Getting hit with an "authentication failed because no credentials were provided" while trying to add the Firebase iOS package to my project. It's driving me nuts!

I have tried all combinations of user settings (clone using HTTPS and SSH) and SSH Key settings (id_ed25519 and id_rsa) -- this was recommended by various Stack Overflow threads.

The token lets me commit/push/etc fine to my repo, but unable to add SPM packages.

I have rebooted the Mac, restarted XCode, Uninstalled and reinstalled XCode 14.3, then 14.2 and then tried 14.1 but it persists.

## Reproduce

1. make sure you have an Apple ID and GitHub accounts added to XCode
2. create new Xcode project
3. follow along setup instructions on firebase.com
4. download and add GoogleService-Info.plist to XCode project folder
5. File - Add Packages
6. Search for `git@github.com:firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git`, select exact version 10.9.0
7. Add Package
8. I tried various combinations of settings for my Github account in Xcode (Clone using HTTPS or SSH, and SSH Key - none, id_ed25519, id_rsa) but it would not work!

This should cause the errors described above (**see above for Loom**, below for Package.resolved error)

## Package.resolved

```
Showing All Messages
PackageIndex.findPackages failed: featureDisabled


firebase-ios-sdk

Updating from git@github.com:firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git
Updating from git@github.com:firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git
git@github.com:firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git: The source control operation failed because the revision “e88a0c9c82ed798e71ecb3e43e555f754b1c654c” could not be found. Make sure a valid revision exists in the repository and try again.



Resolving Package Graph Failed    5/17/23, 12:39 PM    5.6 seconds
```

Comment: What are you trying to do that you need a login? just search for `https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk` when you go to "Add Packages" it is like a 30 second process.

Comment: @loremipsum literally just trying to add the firebase-ios-sdk package to my project so i can use firestore, functions, etc... just normal backend stuff for a mobile app. did you watch the video i shared?

Comment: No, I didn’t watch it. Questions should be all inclusive links break over time and aren’t searchable on SO.

Comment: @loremipsum ‍♂️ alright, no point arguing with this kind of logic